# createElement - select boxes interspersed in the midst of text

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

This is the HTML I'm trying to create:

```
<td>
Tiana is
<select name="U4">...</select>
keen to go to the
<select name="J4">...</select>
market.
</td>
```

As you can see, there is a `<td>` element which contains a prose sentence with select boxes in the midst of it.

It's easy to do with `$('#id').html(...);`. What I want to do is build it using `createElement`. How do you create the select boxes *in the middle* of the other text? The following code is a start :)

```
var doc = document,
    fr = doc.createDocumentFragment(),
    td = doc.createElement("td"),
    sel1 = doc.createElement("select"),
    sel2 = doc.createElement("select");

td.innerHTML = "Tiana is keen to go to the market";

sel1.name = "U4";
sel2.name = "J4";  

fr.appendChild(td);
td.appendChild(sel1);    // But these are not in the middle of the sentence
td.appendChild(sel2);
```

BTW: I recognise, too, that I'll have to create the `select` options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also a function called `createTextNode()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3adocument.createTextNode)) for creating simple text as content. So one solution would be to split your text accordingly, transform it to textnodes and then append it as well:

```
var doc = document,
    fr = doc.createDocumentFragment(),
    td = doc.createElement("td"),
    sel1 = doc.createElement("select"),
    sel2 = doc.createElement("select"),
    text1 = doc.createTextNode( 'Tiana is ' ),
    text2 = doc.createTextNode( ' keen to go to the ' ),
    text3 = doc.createTextNode(  'market' );

sel1.name = "U4";
sel2.name = "J4";  

fr.appendChild(td);
td.appendChild( text1 );
td.appendChild(sel1); 
td.appendChild( text2 );
td.appendChild(sel2);
td.appendChild( text3 );
```

Here you can find an example fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4myFg/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to have this:

```
<td>
<span>Tiana is</span>
<select name="U4">...</select>
<span>keen to go to the</span>
<select name="J4">...</select>
<span>market.</span>
</td>
```

or do this:

```
td.innerHTML = 'Tiana is <select id="U4" name="U4" /> keen to go to the <select id="J4" name="J4" /> market';
var uOpt1 = document.createElement('option');
//Set option properties
td.getElementById('U4').appendChild(uOpt1); //etc
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although Sirko's solution avoids the need to go down the `innerHTML` route :)

Comment: Nowt wrong with innerHTML nowadays ;) Also means you can use this method to replace words in predefined templates with select boxes... something like: ("[person] likes [object]").replace(/\\[(person|object)\\]/, '<select id="drop_$1_' + countPos + '" name="drop_$1_' + countPos + '" />'); Then just populate the selects from a literal containing all possible options for each tagtype (a quick call to td.getElementsByTagName('select')). Which would be kinda cool if you're doing what I assume you're doing with this code :)

Comment: That's pretty similar what I've been doing, Bob, but it's slow!! I want to see if the documentFragment method is faster. Mind you, I think you've convinced me to try a hybrid approach :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?  I adapted the example from [mdn createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5Xe5/1/).

`<div id='org_div1'> The text above has been created dynamically.</div>​`

```
var my_div = null;
var newDiv = null;
var newSelect = null;
var newDiv2 = null;

function addElement()
{
  // create a new div element
  // and give it some content
  newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
  newSelect = document.createElement("select");
  newSelect.innerHTML='<option value="value1">Value 1</option><option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option><option value="value3">Value 3</option>';
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div.
  newDiv.appendChild(newSelect)
   newDiv2 = document.createElement("span");
  newDiv2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Foo"));
  newDiv.appendChild(newDiv2)

  // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
}

addElement()​
```